# I'm having trouble subtracting in C#

Tags: c#, integer, subtraction

So I'm trying to subtract one integer value from another integer value, and I can't seem to get it to work?

Example of my problem,

```cs
int enemyHP = 10;
int playerDamage = 10;
//The player decides to attack the enemy and deals (playerDamage) damage to the enemy

enemyHP - playerDamage //Doesn't work, and I can't find anything else that works.
```

I know I can do `enemyHP-= 10;` but that isn't what I need, because playerDamage can be changed in the game, so it isn't always going to be a fixed number.

Comment: If you do something like `int result = enemyHP - playerDamage;`, then what is the value of `result` after?

Comment: `enemyHP - playerDamage` will not put the result anywhere, you need to put the result into enemyHP like so, `enemyHP = enemyHP - playerDamage`.

Comment: `enemyHP -= playerDamage;` should also work.

Comment: Did "enemyHP - playerDamage "compile without an error?  Its missing a ;

Comment: subtracting is going fine, you're having trouble doing something with the result of the subtraction !

Comment: `enemyHP - playerDamage` is called an __expression__. The result can be __assigned__ to any other int variable or to any of its parts..: `enemyHP = enemyHP - playerDamage `

Comment: Saying "doesn't work" isn't helpful, you need to *read* the error messages. First `; expected` because your statement is terminated. Then when you do that you get `only assignment call increment decrement await and new object expressions can be used as a statement` which seems fairly obvious: this expression is none of those.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you can update the enemy's HP by subtracting the player's damage from it using the following code:

```
enemyHP = enemyHP - playerDamage;
```

Or

```
enemyHP -= playerDamage;
```

Or you can define a new variable and put the result on that:

```
int result = enemyHP - playerDamage;
```